# List view new record category label name TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I create some custom content elements with tt_content, typoscript and tsconfig etc. in a config extension. All works nice.

When changing to list view my custom content element gets listed under 'pen', which seems to be derived from either the extensionname or a table.

How can I set this name? See image.

[image: new record]

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the shown text depends on the table indirectly.
Here is the essential code shown how the name is determined depending on the table-configuration in TCA:

```
$temp = explode(':', substr($v['ctrl']['title'], 9 + strlen($_EXTKEY)));
$langFile = $temp[0];
$thisTitle = $lang->sL('LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/' . $langFile . ':extension.title');
```

This snippet is copied from the file `typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/NewRecordController.php` in the method `renderNewRecordControls()`.
So in the end the text is determined in the language file(s) of your extension.